# How to Improve Stack Overflow's Ask Questions Policy

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

First of all, Stack Overflow deleted the first part of this comment automatically. I am trying to write "Hi Everyone on Meta" in the beginning. (I know this is automatic, but this is how I would like to express this question).

Anyways,

I thought I would blow some of my reputation points by asking this question. I'm super frustrated because I have a 501 reputation, which apparently gives me rights now to approve or not approve new users' questions or something.  (I have a queue now).

But I myself am so frustrated on this site that I can't even ask a question without freaking out that it's going to get shut down.

I really think something needs to change. The point is: If you have a user that is gotten to the point that they can apparently approve or disapprove of questions, but they themselves can not ask a question, this points to an issue.  Since I have seen/heard of other people feeling bullied on this site, I thought this was a good time to raise my concern.

Maybe allow people to cluster questions, instead of marking them as duplicates?

Tag questions as "novice" or "newbie" so that people who are getting oriented in programming aren't just shut down by users who have poor communication skills, but high "stack overflow reputations" - Maybe allow one question to have multiple titles added to it, so that it is more likely to show up in all of the various searches that people do.

For example, I'll get marked as "duplicate" but when I look at the title of the post that is marked, I would have NEVER found it via search.

It would also be nice if there were a multiple-choice box, where you have to explain *why* you down-voted a question. (For example, my reputation has not changed in a really long time. Coincidentally, after posting this, one question that always only got up votes suddenly got down-votes).  This would also make it less mysterious. As is, you're just getting a ruler smacked on your knuckles (figuratively speaking) with no reason why, etc.

Anyone else have any ideas too ... or just generally want to let me know how right I am !? lol. (That is a joke)

The response I've gotten so far is, in essence, that if I don't like the site, why not just leave.  Counter point: If you don't want to read people's feedback, ideas, and/or complaints, why not just "leave" this question?

Comment: Voting on meta is different and doesn't affect your reputation.

Comment: One problem I see is shown in the way you've phrased something: *I'll get marked as "duplicate"*. The *question* was marked as a duplicate, not you. In fact, it has nothing to do with you. Someone, or several people, looked at the question, recognized it as having been asked before, and took action to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: So you can't blow any rep, can't use salutations, don't actually have a "queue", there is no "clustering", hi-rep users got there by helping users like you, can't use multiple titles, users routinely find SO posts back with Google queries.  But yes, having this little insight in how the site works inevitably will prove to be frustrating.  Consider it is just not the place to hang your hat.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, did you not know that I was referring to my question and not literally myself?  The point is that because it is a duplicate, you get down-voted/ penalized, prevented from getting answers that are more specific to your exact situation.

Comment: @Maiya, regarding your latest edit, that has been [suggested and rejected many, many times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin).

Comment: @Maiya "did you not know that I was referring to my question and not literally myself?" - no. We see people coming to meta with "you punished *me* with high quality answers provided in duplicates" all the time. It is very hard to see that you've used "I" as "question" in the post. Don't forget that many of posters on meta (as well as on the main site) are coming from places where English is not the native language and recognizing such things like referring to the question as "I" is hard.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery In other words many, many people have asked for it and been ignored.

Comment: @HansPassant You have completely missed my points. 1) I am aware that those features don't exist. That's why it is a "request." 2) I actually do have a queue of questions for me to look at.  I got this because I invested time helping other users; yet I don't feel comfortable asking questions myself and see a lot of other people who feel the same as I do getting shot down, in the exact same way you have shot down my comments.  3) I am aware of google. Cheers. Your reply is basically, "if you don't like it leave."  That may be an accurate tagline for the site (which, again, is my point).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'll try to be more aware of that. I believed the meaning would translate across languages because, even though my question is penalized, it is my ability to ask more questions that is affected. If you get down-votes, you can't ask more questions. And if it's marked as a duplicate, you can't get specific help.

Comment: *You can ask a bad advanced questions and people leave it alone.* Do you have an example?

Comment: @Maiya so you downvoted posts at least 3 times... presumably you provided detailed comments why... and yet there were no reason to remove those downvotes. Instead of telling that you disagree with every base rule of the site it may be better to ask how to improve your commenting skills so people actually react poitively to your comments about downvtes and act on those... That actually may help with your crusade to make everyone leave comments on all sorts of votes....

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov 1) I have never down-voted a question. I always just give comments/ suggestions to try to improve it. The only time I have given a downvote is to the answer when ppl were being smug and/or rude, etc.  2) Nowhere in my post did I say that down-voting should be entirely taken away, so not sure why you're citing any of my votes at all. 3) If I wanted to ask how to improve my commenting skills, I would have asked that. I asked the question that I wanted to ask. 4) Writing one post on meta does not constitute a "crusade" even if you happen to not like my comment.

Comment: I see - so you are fine that posts you downvoted and commented on were not improved after your comments... Many people have hard time dealing with that which is one of many reasons why feature "require comment on (down)votes" still does not have solution that can be implemented. While you believe all such suggestions were completely ignored you may want to spend couple minutes looking through https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/357436?lq=1 to see if maybe someone had reasons why that feature would not bring results you probably expect...

Comment: *"The only time I have given a downvote is to the answer when ppl were being smug and/or rude"* — You should really vote on *technical accuracy* and *overall usefulness* of a post. If a post becomes less useful due to an overabundance of smugness or rudeness, yeah, that's probably a reason to downvote; in extreme cases flag it for moderator attention. If you're not exercising your votes to downvote wrong and/or not useful content, you really should start doing that.

Comment: Dupe are not a bad thing. Dupe are usefull even for the dupe askers. When someone flag a dupe, The system add a "_Does this answer your question? [Link here]_". And There is a lot of new usr, that answer to that canned comment with a thanks. See the dupe as a sign post in the direction of your solution. We are like a busy supermarket, you had issue finding something, someone came and tell you it's right there. That's how dupe flaging work. It's not a shutup. It block submiting answer so no one can trash the alley dropping the item at your feet.

Comment: @xdt I was with you there until that very last analogy… wut? 

Comment: @deceze, Ho translation issue. How do you call the place between 2 store shelf, where people walk ? I mean peoples will go in the right Store shelf pick the right item and bring it back to you with copy past.  For years. Seeing you question people will continue to bring the wanted item. Some won't even go to the right shelf. They will pick up the item on the ground and drop it again. "Trashing" the place.

Comment: @xdt "Aisle" would be the appropriate word there. But that wasn't really the confusion here. The rest of the analogy was… somewhat strenuous… Anyway, I think I got what you mean.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yep. I'm fine with it. That's why I did the votes that I did. I have only up-voted questions, actually. The down-votes were answers where the people were overtly rude. That's easy to fix, and I would be happy to change the extremely sparse number/ infintesimaly few down-votes that I have ever cast. Yes. I am fine with that. Also, it would be nice if they sent an alert, so you could get notified if someone tried to fix it.

Comment: @xdt I'm not against duplicates. I'm only against locking them and down-voting them. And I think that adding a feature where different users can add alternate titles to posts would cut down on duplicates.

Comment: Frankly, many users have trouble coming up with *one* good title. Not sure how realistically useful allowing multiple would be.

Comment: @deceze That's exactly the point. The questioner could put whatever they want. Other people could add additional titles to the post that would show up in search results.

Comment: Currently other people can edit the post to *fix* the *one* title into something good. I think that's more useful than allowing multiple titles. How would multiple titles show up in the question and/or list views? Seems like a lot of additional clutter if it's all displayed. If it's *not* displayed and only used as search keywords… the search already looks at the body content too, so there's enough room to add additional content for searchability.

Comment: @Maiya Cody already explained that using "titles" (actually whole posts) for search is exactly how feature works now (duplcates are indexed but redirected to target one when navigating to it for anonymous users). And target of the duplicate already lists all duplcates (i.e. link I gave you earlier with list of all duplicates to "why downvote comments")... You may want to clarify how you envision your feature to look like... I.e. "all duplicates should show all titles for all posts duplicated to the same one" (use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/ as sample for your UI )

Comment: That "What is NRE and how to fix it" has decent number ([4K+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/4660142?lq=1)) of questions that use it as duplicate target - so if you can design UI that nicely shows all 4858 different titles wherever you wanted them to show up I'm sure such feature request would get way more upbeat (not necessary more positive) welcome.

Comment: @deceze My idea is to have a limited number of alt titles, because titles are much more specific than the text the body, so they are better pointers. Multiple titles can incorporate the fact that there are many different angles from which be looking from. I think they could show up as a drop down list on the question, and in the list views, maybe a scroll sideways.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was aware that my question would not be received well. I've seen how other people have been replied to on the site. I think that's clear in my question.

Comment: @BSMD I'm sure I can go find them. I'm not really getting that it would be good use of my time, though. This is not a collaborative, creative vibe here.  I've noticed, and chatted with others about the fact that if your code is more advanced, people tend to leave it alone but beginner questions seem to get shot down even when they meet the criteria and/or come very close.

Comment: *"If you have a user that is gotten to the point that they can apparently approve or disapprove of questions, but they themselves can not ask a question, this points to an issue."* — That is indeed an interesting point that has so far gotten quite lost. It'd be interesting to talk about why exactly you "can't ask questions." Maybe mull that point over for a little longer and post a new topic focused on just that.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the feedback. I actually have seen people post about exactly those points/ not being able to ask questions, but the response is rigid and combative. Also, I don't want to focus the question on the fact that I have question-approving-privileges because I think the matter applies to people who don't.

Comment: @HansPassant 1) The question was not referring to the reputation points of others anywhere. Thus your smug comment about how people gain their reputation points is just your own issue. 2) The question was soliciting new ideas, not repetitive shut-downs that can be found all over meta already, so you're providing zero new info there. 3) Did you have a formal education when you were first learning programming? Or a guide? If so, you could be more open to learning about how beginners are shut out from asking questions when they don't have that same orientation.

Answer (score 26):

> First of all, Stack Overflow deleted the first part of this comment automatically. I am trying to write "Hi Everyone on Meta" in the beginning.

There is never a reason to start posts with "Hi", including on Meta; that's why it is removed automatically.

> I thought I would blow some of my reputation points by asking this question.

Reputation doesn't exist on Meta, so you can't lose anything.

> I'm super frustrated because I have a 501 reputation, which apparently gives me rights now to approve or not approve new users' questions or something. (I have a queue now).
>
> But I myself am so frustrated on this site that I can't even ask a question without freaking out that it's going to get shut down.
>
> I really think something needs to change. I'm fed up.

You need to be a lot more clear about what exactly it is that's making you "frustrated" or "fed up".

Having a question marked as a duplicate is ***not*** a punishment or anything bad. It just means the question has already been asked and answered on this site. Yes, sometimes the duplicates are obvious, and your own research should have turned them up. But other times, they're not at all obvious, and someone with expertise in the topic/domain is needed to find them. That's OK: the system is designed to allow that. The advantage of having your question marked as a duplicate is that you can immediately get an answer. Furthermore, you know that the answers have been vetted by the community over time, accruing votes and edits that a brand-new answer to your question wouldn't have the time to get.

> Tag questions as "novice" or "newbie" so that people who are getting oriented in programming aren't just shut down by users who have poor communication skills, but high "stack overflow reputations."

This has been proposed multiple times, but isn't going to happen. We don't close questions on Stack Overflow because they are "too newbie". That's not a problem. We do, however, have strict quality standards and other specific requirements for questions, which you can read about in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We have these requirements because experience has taught us that these features are required in order for a question to work in our Q&A format. Thus, a newbie site wouldn't solve anything anyway, since it would still use the same Q&A format. There is the additional problem that a newbie site wouldn't be able to attract experts to answer the questions, resulting in a quality vacuum—and since high-quality content is probably what brings newbies to Stack Overflow anyway, this would kind of be shooting ourselves in the foot.

(Speaking of duplicates, you can easily find many questions covering this topic of bifurcating Stack Overflow into a "beginner" and "expert" site by searching Meta.)

Also, please stop accusing people who help to curate this site of having "poor communication skills" or operating with less-than-pure motives. We have a very engaged community of users who volunteer their free time to maintain the quality of this site. We should all be *thankful* for the work that they do. Mistakes may sometimes be made, but they are also easily corrected. There is absolutely no evidence that anyone who works to moderate this site is motivated by reputation, and, in fact, moderation/curation activities *don't gain you any reputation*, so ascribing that motivation doesn't even make sense.

> Maybe allow one question to have multiple titles added to it, so that it is more likely to show up in all of the various searches that people do.

This is almost literally the way our "duplicate" system is designed to work. You see, each new question that is marked as a duplicate serves as a *pointer*, redirecting to the "master" question. Thus, the "master" question *does* actually have multiple titles associated with it, making it more likely to be found in the future, regardless of which search terms are used. Eventually, the idea is that a question will be asked in all of the common ways, providing complete coverage of the associated search terms. We want all of these different permutations to redirect back to the "master" question in order to keep the answers all in one place for easy maintenance.

Comment: Re: "Having a question marked as a duplicate is not a punishment or anything bad"  It actually is. People down-vote it if it is duplicate, and it gets locked, so people can not answer your question specifically.  The down-votes mean you can't ask more questions. If you edit it, those who down-vote it don't look at it to change their vote.

Comment: Re: "We don't close questions on Stack Overflow because they are "too newbie."  I totally disagree. Spoken to lots of newbies that get their questions shot down, and the newbies exclaim, "Well, if I had known [whatever info they were supposed to have included] I wouldn't have had the  question in the first place!" I think it's a problem with SO having poor communication skills for non-tech people. You can ask a bad advanced questions and people leave it alone. But ask a good newbie question and they shoot it down.

Comment: re: "This is almost literally the way our "duplicate" system is designed to work."  No, it absolutely does not. When someone is asking a question, it can be asked from many different angles. Allowing multiple alternative titles to be added by other users would cut down on duplicates. (Again, asking a duplicate question gets you down-voted and penalizes your right to ask questions, etc).

Comment: re: "duplicate question votes" This is another argument in favor of a multiple choice/ comment box for down-votes. People seem to be under the impression that it is their duty to down-vote both beginner questions and duplicate questions.

Comment: Lack of research effort is a common reason to downvote, so much so that it is documented in the tooltip on the downvote arrow. *Some* duplicate questions are sufficiently lacking in research effort that it makes sense to downvote them. Others are not. I covered this distinction in my answer. Also...you're gonna need a lot more than a couple of downvotes on dupe questions to get banned from asking. That's a total quality metric, and has almost no false-positives in my experience.

Comment: You identify "poor communication skills" as the problem for newbies, but it's not the real problem. The real problem is that folks operate under the mistaken assumption that this site is a help desk, where any question can be asked. That's not the case. We have very strict standards/requirements for questions, and we only allow certain types of questions. If your question isn't accepted here, well, sorry, but you're out of luck. Regardless of experience level. We don't do *tutorials*, which is often what newbies need. They just don't work in our format. Our model is closer to Wikipedia.

Comment: I'm not even sure what all the words here are for. It boils down to me saying that a lot of people have my same complaints, but get shut down. And then you giving the same canned answers that are given ad infinitum and shutting down these same complaints. I am aware of what Stack Overflow is. Cheers.

Comment: People disagreeing with you is not the same as getting "shut down".

Comment: I am aware of that. I am not referring to disagreement.

Comment: @Maiya If you're "aware what Stack Overflow is" and don't like what it is: Why do you bother to come here and get frustrated? Is it because of the quality of the answers? If it is, ask yourself *why* the quality is so good - it's *because* the site has the restrictions and rules about which you complain. It's that simple. If everything were allowed, SO would be like every other "forum" out there; the experts wouldn't be here to answer; poor content would be left, just like everywhere else.

Comment: @CindyMeister 1) Your question boils down to, if you don't like it then leave. That's not new information. 2) Why is there a forum for feedback if a frustrated user should "just leave." That is the uncreative and smug type of answer that a lot of people don't like. 3) I did not say that "everything" should be allowed; so, the rest of the comment is not a good-faith dialogue. Cheers.

Comment: @Maiya nobody suggested you left - the entire comment was to remind you why are you still here. You are here (presumably) for the quality. Your suggestion is to drop the quality - the one reason you are still around. If that assumption is incorrect, then what *does* motivate you to stay here? Because it might still be a transitive property of the quality standards.

Comment: @VLAZ They literally said "why do you bother coming here" ... That's the same as saying "leave if you don't like it." I'm not getting the quality out of the site, actually. I find that I mostly only answer questions, but don't get the help in being able to ask them. That's kind of my whole point. And I know other people in real life that feel the same.

Comment: @Maiya No, I wrote "Why do you bother to come here and get frustrated?" You've taken the statement out of context, changed the wording, then twisted what was meant. You say coming here frustrates you - I ask *why* you do that to yourself? I never say you should leave - what I do say is that *if* the quality of the site is what makes you come, even if you feel frustrated, then it makes little sense to reduce that quality <shrug>

Comment: @Maiya in other words: you basically say coming to stack is difficult and frustrating to you. I dunno for you... but I try not to stay exposed to things that are difficult or frustrating..... Except if they bring me something I need. So, Cindy's question was more along the lines of "even with the frustration, I think you come back to Stack because its got content you want to use".... that very content is there *because* of a lot of the rules you seem to disagree with. Stack is just suffering from it's own success. What used to be "research"->"find stack"->"find solution", became "ask stack".

Comment: @Patrice No. I'm saying that there's obviously a glitch in a system that allows someone to review and approve questions of other users; but that person themselves does not even feel comfortable asking a question.  Being as so many people get shut out when commenting on their experiences of feeling bullied on the site, I thought I would use this as a point to express my views. Whether I stay or leave will by my choice. I'm moving on to other conversations now. Cheers.

Comment: @Maiya if any user thinks that downvotes etc. are any kind of bullying, they have no experience of real bullying, cyber or physical.  They are totally clueless and don't care about real victims, only for the value of the word to abuse curators.

Comment: @MartinJames That's a bit dramatic.

Comment: It is possibly a bit dramatic.  But probably fundamentally true.

Comment: @StephenC  People are able to distinguish the context in which a word is used and extrapolate where it lies on the spectrum. We don't have to speak like dogmatic absolutists.

Comment: I know that.  I am saying that what Martin is saying is fundamentally correct.   Whether you think it is "dramatic" or not.

Comment: @StephenC Yes, I got that. My reply indicates that I think it is not correct. To say that you can only ever use a word in its most extreme interpretation; and that any other use of the word indicates that you don't comprehend what that word means in a different context is ... false.